# How to specify which elements to a:hover on

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so the +Kendrick element is not underlined, but the Gmail and Images elements remain underlined when hovered over, any help would be appreciated, thanks

Relevant HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">+Kendrick</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gmail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Relevant CSS

```
#header {
    background-color: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#header ul {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

li {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;
    display: inline;
}

#header ul li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

ul a:hover first-child {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it there.  You just needed to finish the last css style like this

```
#header ul li:first-child a:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpuzmee5/)